# Divide and Conquer Matrix Multiplication

Tags: algorithm, math, matrix, multiplication

I am having trouble getting divide and conquer matrix multiplication to work. From what I understand, you split the matrices of size nxn into quadrants (each quadrant is n/2) and then you do:

```
C11 = A11⋅ B11 + A12 ⋅ B21   
C12 = A11⋅ B12 + A12 ⋅ B22  
C21 = A21 ⋅ B11 + A22 ⋅ B21  
C22 = A21 ⋅ B12 + A22 ⋅ B22
```

My output for divide and conquer is really large and I'm having trouble figuring out the problem as I am not very good with recursion.

example output:

Original Matrix A:

```
4 0 4 3   
5 4 0 4   
4 0 4 0  
4 1 1 1
```

A x A

Classical:

```
44 3 35 15  
56 20 24 35  
32 0 32 12  
29 5 21 17
```

Divide and Conquer:

```
992 24 632 408  
1600 272 720 1232   
512 0 512 384  
460 17 405 497
```

Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong for divide and conquer? All my matrices are `int[][]` and classical method is the traditional 3 for loop matrix multiplication

Comment: Why is it that you want to do matrix multiplication this way? If you are interested in raw performance there are numeric libraries available that I am sure would be faster than what you could write on your own in a reasonable amount of time. If you are interested in learning about numeric computing I would start with loop tiling (wikipedia has an article) instead of a recursive solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are recursively calling `divideAndConquer` in the wrong way. What your function does is square a matrix. In order for divide and conquer matrix multiplication to work, it needs to be able to multiply two potentially different matrixes together.

It should look something like this:

```
private static int[][] divideAndConquer(int[][] matrixA, int[][] matrixB){
    if (matrixA.length == 2){
         //calculate and return base case
    }
    else {
        //make a11, b11, a12, b12 etc. by dividing a and b into quarters      
        int[][] c11 = addMatrix(divideAndConquer(a11,b11),divideAndConquer(a12,b21));
        int[][] c12 = addMatrix(divideAndConquer(a11,b12),divideAndConquer(a12,b22));
        int[][] c21 = addMatrix(divideAndConquer(a21,b11),divideAndConquer(a22,b21));
        int[][] c22 = addMatrix(divideAndConquer(a21,b12),divideAndConquer(a22,b22));
        //combine result quarters into one result matrix and return
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Some debugging approaches to try:

- Try some very simple test matrices as input (e.g. all zeros, with a one or a few strategic ones).  You may see a pattern in the "failures" that will show you where your error(s) are.
- Make sure your "classical" approach is giving you correct answers.  For small matrices, you can use Woflram Alpha on-line to test answers:  http://www.wolframalpha.com/examples/Matrices.html
- To debug recursion:  add `printf()` statements at the entry and exit of your function, including the invocation arguments.  Run your test matrix, write the output to a log file, and open the log file with a text editor.  Step through each case, writing your notes alongside in the editor making sure it's working correctly at each step.  Add more `printf()` statements and run again if needed.

Good luck with the homework!

Comment: my classical approach does give me the right answers. I'll try making a matrix of all 1s instead of 0 because I doubt that a matrix of 0s will work since adding or multiplying with 0 will be 0.

Comment: Yes, a matrix of all zeros will give you zero. But add a FEW strategic ones, (like all in one column or row or diagonal) will give you some better tests.

Answer (score 2):

> Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong for divide and conquer?

Yes:

```
   int[][] a = divideAndConquer(topLeft);
   int[][] b = divideAndConquer(topRight);
   int[][] c = divideAndConquer(bottomLeft);
   int[][] d = divideAndConquer(bottomRight);

   int[][] c11 = addMatrix(classical(a,a),classical(b,c));
   int[][] c12 = addMatrix(classical(a,b),classical(b,d));
   int[][] c21 = addMatrix(classical(c,a),classical(d,c));
   int[][] c22 = addMatrix(classical(c,b),classical(d,d));
```

You are going through an extra multiplication step here: you shouldn't be calling both `divideAndConquer()` and `classical()`.

What you are effectively doing is:

```
C11 = (A11^2)⋅(B11^2) + (A12^2)⋅(B21^2)
C12 = (A11^2)⋅(B12^2) + (A12^2)⋅(B22^2)
C21 = (A21^2)⋅(B11^2) + (A22^2)⋅(B21^2)
C22 = (A21^2)⋅(B12^2) + (A22^2)⋅(B22^2)
```

which is not correct.

1. First, remove the `divideAndConquer()` calls, and replace a/b/c/d by topLeft/topRight/etc.
   See if it gives you the proper results.
2. Your `divideAndConquer()` method needs a pair of input parameters, so you can use A*B. Once you get that working, get rid of the calls to `classical()`, and use `divideAndConquer()` instead. (or save them for matrices that are not a multiple of 2 in length.)

Answer (score 1):

You might find the Wiki article on [Strassen's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strassen_algorithm) helpful.

Comment: I will be implementing Strassens algorithm next, but I need divide and conquer as well.