# Matrix Multiplication using divide and conquer

Tags: c, algorithm, matrix, matrix-multiplication

The problem is that the speed is very slow, terrible slow, even under a small n, for example: when n=1024, there must be something wrong, anyone?

I didn't create new matrix C whenever function call, I add the new result to the previous result which is stored in original matrix C when base case occurs.

```
int **matA,**matB,**matC;

    void matmul_div_rec(int Arow,int Acol,int Brow,int Bcol,int n) {
        if(n==1)
        {
            matC[Arow][Bcol]+=matA[Arow][Acol]*matB[Brow][Bcol];
        }
        else
        {
            matmul_div_rec(Arow+0,Acol+0,Brow+0,Bcol+0,n/2);
            matmul_div_rec(Arow+0,Acol+n/2,Brow+n/2,Bcol+0,n/2);
            matmul_div_rec(Arow+0,Acol+0,Brow+0,Bcol+n/2,n/2);
            matmul_div_rec(Arow+0,Acol+n/2,Brow+n/2,Bcol+n/2,n/2);
            matmul_div_rec(Arow+n/2,Acol+0,Brow+0,Bcol+0,n/2);
            matmul_div_rec(Arow+n/2,Acol+n/2,Brow+n/2,Bcol+0,n/2);
            matmul_div_rec(Arow+n/2,Acol+0,Brow+0,Bcol+n/2,n/2);
            matmul_div_rec(Arow+n/2,Acol+n/2,Brow+n/2,Bcol+n/2,n/2);
        }
        return; }
int main()
{
    matmul_div_rec(0,0,0,0,n); //n must be the power of 2

}
```

Comment: Given the size of your matrices, I am guessing they are sparse matrices (mostly zeros). You can save a lot of space and time if you treat them as such.

Comment: Read about strassen way to multiplication of matrix, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4846938/divide-and-conquer-matrix-multiplication    http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/strassens-matrix-multiplication/   http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/strassens-matrix-multiplication/

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12922031/recursive-matrix-multiplication

Comment: For n=1024, This performs 2^30~=1B multiply-adds, and makes 1227133512~=1.2B recursive function calls (which also require a few more adds and calculation of n/2). A naive implementation of matrix multiply makes the same number of multiply-adds, but no recursive function calls.

Comment: Paolo D'Alberto maintains a special web site [http://www.fastmmw.com](http://www.fastmmw.com) [FastMMW](http://www.fastmmw.com) devoted to practical matrix multiplication algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

As briefly discussed in, for instance, [this](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4631317/?reload=true) paper, an implementation of Strassen's algorithm (even if it is correct) has a competitive performance only if some additional ideas are used. These include for instance using the so-called [Morton order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-order_curve) layout for matrix storage in memory to obtain an easier way to address the submatrices and improves the caching behaviour via better memory locality. Furthermore, there is a potential improvement by using [SIMD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMD) for parallelization of matrix addition at the base case of the recursion.

Comment: The code in the question isn't Strassen. It's a naive matrix multiply algorithm written in a "divide and conquer" recursive style.